# Inconsistent Accuracy Between Training and Validation Using Same Dataset and Model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, debugging, classification, training-data

I am encountering a perplexing issue while training a deep learning model using TensorFlow/Keras. Despite using the same dataset for both training and validation, I am observing a significant discrepancy in accuracy and loss between the two. I am seeking insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Problem Description:

I am using a ResNet 18 architecture for a binary classification task.
The same dataset is used for both training and validation.
There is no data augmentation, dropout, or batch normalization involved.
Despite the identical data, the training accuracy is significantly different from the validation accuracy.

Model

```
# ResNet 18
def model_resnet_set(input_shape):
    input_tensor = Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    # Initial convolution layer
    x = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(input_tensor)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)

    # Residual blocks
    x = residual_block(x, 64, 2)
    x = residual_block(x, 128, 2, stride=2)
    x = residual_block(x, 256, 2, stride=2)
    x = residual_block(x, 512, 2, stride=2)
    
    # Global average pooling and classification head
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=x)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),metrics=["accuracy"]) 
    return model
    
    
def residual_block(x, filters, blocks, stride=1):
    shortcut = x
    for i in range(blocks):
        if i == 0:
            shortcut = Conv2D(filters, (1, 1), strides=(stride, stride))(shortcut)
            shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)
        x = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), strides=(stride, stride), padding='same')(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        stride = 1  # Only the first convolution in the block uses the specified stride
    x = tf.keras.layers.add([x, shortcut])
    return x
```

To load the image, I just simply use

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
```

To append the image to a list.

For training, I use

```
history = model.fit(train_set,labels,epochs=10,validation_data=(train_set,labels), batch_size = 128)
```

Result shown for training as

```
12/12 [==============================] - 12s 246ms/step - loss: 0.4158 - accuracy: 0.7966 - val_loss: 1.0283 - val_accuracy: 0.5024
Epoch 2/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 134ms/step - loss: 0.3266 - accuracy: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.6288 - val_accuracy: 0.7831
Epoch 3/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 159ms/step - loss: 0.2529 - accuracy: 0.8983 - val_loss: 1.5992 - val_accuracy: 0.4997
Epoch 4/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 129ms/step - loss: 0.2207 - accuracy: 0.9031 - val_loss: 2.2351 - val_accuracy: 0.4997
Epoch 5/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 157ms/step - loss: 0.1795 - accuracy: 0.9329 - val_loss: 2.6216 - val_accuracy: 0.4997
```

Possible reason why it caused this problem and possible solution for that. Or just some insight where the problem might occured

Comment: You wrote `There is no data augmentation, dropout, or batch normalization involved`. But in your model code, there are `BatchNormalization` and `Dropout` layers?